# Nginx + Unicorn + Rails not allowing more than 6 request until any tcp connection is free

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, tcp

I have an application in Ruby on Rails running with unicorn and nginx. I have a few request which takes some time to process because of huge DB.

Till 6 request I am able to browse my application with out any delay. When I ran `netstat -n | grep 'CONNECTED'` it says

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37992166 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37989365 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37993053 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37992166 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37989335 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37993083 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
```

and when I ran `netstat -n | grep 'CONNECTING'` it shows nothing.

But after 6 request when I ran the same command again apart from the above command it says

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING     37989334 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTING     37993089 /home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
```

Even when I tried to send request from Firefox it adds to the `CONNECTING` things and wait until the tcp is free if I am not wrong.

Please help me what should I do to resolve this error. Thanks

This is how my `unicorn.rb` looks like

```
working_directory "/home/user/myapp/current"
pid "/home/user/myapp/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/user/myapp/shared/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/user/myapp/shared/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock", backlog: 64
worker_processes 6

preload_app true

timeout 600

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

    # Quit the old unicorn process
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
      begin
        Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
        # someone else did our job for us
      end
    end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
            Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool']  = ENV['DB_POOL']  || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 10
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Comment: what's your unicorn.rb look like?

Comment: Updated my question with `unicorn.rb`

Comment: And what's `Rails.application.config.database_configuration['production']['pool']` report (on your production node)

Comment: It says nil and that is why added separate `pool` in next line. Also when I changed the worker from 6 to 20 it is now accepting 20 request. So is this going to block other user's request when I am the only one who is creating 20 request

Answer (score 2):

Unicorn is a single-threaded application server. That means: a single unicorn worker process can handle only exactly one request at any time.

Since you have configured the `worker_processes` count to 6 in your `unicorn.rb`, that's the exact number of concurrent requests your app can handle.

To solve this, you can either increase the number of worker processes or (if your app is multi-thread capable) use a different application server which allows the use of multiple threads in a process, each of which then can handle a single requests. Common application servers for this kind of deployment are [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) and [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/).